# Passing values ​to an array within a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to make a program in C++ in which the number of mathematical signs are counted. I am using `isdigit` to figure this out, but when I pass the value of my string, it gives me a warning.

This is the code that I have. The line `digito[i] = entrada[i]` is where I think the problem lies, but I do not understand why.

```
cout << "Input the operation" << endl;
cin >> input;
string digit[] = { "" };
string sign[]={""};
int cn = 0, cs = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
    if (isdigit(input[i])) {
        cout << "There is a digit in position " << i << endl;
        cn += 1;
        digit[i] = input[i];
    }
    else {
        cout << "There is a sign in position " << i << endl;
        // sign[i] = input[i];
        cs += 1;
        sign[i] = input[i];
    }
}
```

It takes me to this code as the problem:

```
static _CONSTEXPR17 void assign(char& _Left, const char& _Right) noexcept
{ // assign an element
    _Left = _Right;
}
```

Comment: English, please.

Comment: Hector, lo he convertido a inglés, pero es posible que desees comprobarlo, ya que usé Google Translate, que es notoriamente poco confiable. Alternativamente, hay un sitio SO en español si prefiere su idioma nativo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I translated it to English! @paxdiablo (Spanish, my native language).

Answer (score 2):

Those two strings are problematic. You've unnecessarily declared them as arrays with one element each, and initialized each string to empty.

```
string digito[] = { "" };
string signo[]={""};
```

Yet afterwards, you're indexing them with non-zero indices:

```
digito[i] = entrada[i];
```

This line is problematic because of two reasons; going beyond the array bounds, and incompatible types.

`digito[i]` is the type of `std::string` (because `digito` is `std::string[]`), while `entrada[i]` is `char` (assuming `entrada` is `std::string`). `std::string` has an overload of its `operator=` that allows assigning to a single character, but that's not what you want here, I assume.

As for the second problem, `std::string` requires you to enlarge it before you random-access it at a given index. The best way to do this in this case would be during construction, dropping the erroneous array use:

```
std::cin >> entrada;
std::string digito(entrada.size(), ' ');
std::string signo(entrada.size(), ' ');
```

---

That being said, I'm not sure if this code does what you want it to. Given an input string of:

```
2+2/3
```

You'll get two such strings:

```
digito = "2 2 3"
signo  = " + / "
```

If your *actual* goal was to tokenize the input (divide into numbers and operators), a much better way would be to use either two `std::vector<char>`s, or, even better:

```
using Number = int;
enum class Operator { Plus, Minus, Div, Mul };
using Token = std::variant<Number, Operator>
using Sequence = std::vector<Token>;
```

A consistent, strongly-typed data model will make it much easier to write correct code that produces it and operates on the results afterwards.